# Can 気 be used for advice?

Tags: grammar, translation, words, kanji

I’m reading an article about the corona virus. They’re giving instructions to follow in order to prevent reappearance of the virus.

> 緊急事態宣言が終わっても、新しいコロナウイルスはなくなっていないので、気をつけなければなりません。
>
> 毎日の生活では、次のようなことに気をつける必要があります

[image]

This is from Weblio. I scrolled through all of the definitions but they refer to emotions and mood.

From my understanding of the article, they’re giving instructions to follow, why are they using 気? Why not 注意? I can’t find a definition for 気 which fits.

Source:

https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10012444741000/k10012444741000.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

気 is very common word so it has many meanings. I think you were close.

[image]

気 exactly has the meaning of attention or care. 気をつける in the example context means "to be careful" or "to take care".

By the way, almost all the Japanese students start a class with a weird command 「起立。気をつけ。礼」 which means "Stand up. Attention. Bow."

Comment: Thank you for the tidbit about Japanese class student.

Comment: Compare with [気にする](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%B0%97%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B) and [気になる](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%B0%97%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B)